# What is the error type that I will get if batch commit fails and how do import such error

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Google Cloud function that has batch write to Firestore.  I would like to know what type of error I might get if the commit fails and how to import such an error.  I am using Typescript.   Here is the code that I have:

```
import {getFirestore} from 'firebase-admin/firestore';
// Which error do I need to import and how do I import it.


const db = getFirestore();

// inside cloud function 
try {
  const batch = db.batch();
  // ...
  // ...
  await batch.commit();
} catch (error) {
  // I want to know the type of "error" over here and how to import it
  // because I am using Typescript
}
```

Comment: You can look at the [source code](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore) and see what it does. I wouldn't be surprised if there is no special error type. Any instance of Error can be used to indicate failure - there is no requirement that they be specially typed. Also, the [API reference](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest) doesn't say anything about error type.

Comment: The samples you mentioned are for JavaScript not for typescript.

Comment: TypeScript *is* JavaScript, with type information added. It gets converted to JavaScript before it's executed by node. It's all the same code in the end.  Same SDK in either case.

Comment: I am aware that Typescript is Javascript, but I am not able to find out where FirestoreError is.  How do I import it?  What are the exact errors that I would get with the commit().  This is important, because that will help me find out the code of the error.

Comment: If there is a FirestoreError object to be found, it will be in that Firestore SDK source code I linked.  It is, in fact, TypeScript.  You have to dig into that repo to find it.

Comment: As mentioned by Renaud at [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52737186/17477508) you can also use the catch function on the returned promise object instead of using async/await. **(OR)** You can get the [type of error to be expected during the transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#firestoreerrorcode). And also have a look at [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61271336/17477508) which might help.

```

```